# question about the eth MPT

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries

From the docs https://eth.wiki/en/fundamentals/patricia-tree, there is extended code about the compact encode as follow:

```
def compact_encode(hexarray):
    term = 1 if hexarray[-1] == 16 else 0
    if term: hexarray = hexarray[:-1]
    oddlen = len(hexarray) % 2
    flags = 2 * term + oddlen
    if oddlen:
        hexarray = [flags] + hexarray
    else:
        hexarray = [flags] + [0] + hexarray
    // hexarray now has an even length whose first nibble is the flags.
    o = ''
    for i in range(0,len(hexarray),2):
        o += chr(16 * hexarray[i] + hexarray[i+1])
    return o
```

what does the first line `term = 1 if hexarray[-1] == 16 else 0` mean? what does the `hexarray[-1] == 16` mean?

Thank you

Comment: It is python syntax `hexarray[-1]` is the last element in `hexarray`, `hexarray[-2]` is the penultimate, and so on. Same with `term = 1 if condition else 0`, `term` will be 1 if `condition` is true and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got the answer.
The 16 is the terminator of the HP encoding. For MPT, if the node is a leaf node, the last item of the compacted key array will be 16.

Here are some examples:

if x includes the terminator t!=0, otherwise t=0

case 1:

t=0, x={1,2,3,4,5} and x are (nibble)
f(t)=0, ||x||=5 => odd
HP(x,t) = {16(0+1)+1, 16*2+3,16*4+5}
= {0x11, 0x23, 0x45}

case 2:

t=0, x={0,1,2,3,4,5} and x are (nibble)
f(t)=0, ||x||=6 => even
HP(x,t) = {0, 16*0+1,16*2+3, 16*4+5}
= {0x00, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45}

case 3:

t!=0, x={15,1,12,11,8,16} (16 is terminator, not calculated as length)
HP(x,t) = {16*3+f, 16*1+c, 16*b+8}
= {0x3f, 0x1c, 0xb8}

case 4:

t!=0, x={0,15,1,12,11,8,16} (16 is the terminator，not calculated as length)
HP(x,t) = {16*2, 16*0+f, 16*1+c, 16*b+8}
= {0x20, 0x0f, 0x1c, 0xb8}